# Selectively extract data from multi-level JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement, loops

I have a multi-level JSON object which is contains an array of 143 other objects.

Running console.log(obj) on this object displays:

```
0: Object
  ActFTEs: 0.00
  Actual: 11111
  Bud_Month: "October"
  FY_CD: 2013
  Mission_Name: "RST"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
  ActFTEs: 0.00
  Actual: 10000
  Bud_Month: "FY Total"
  FY_CD: 2013
  Mission_Name: "RST"
```

etc.... through all 143 objects.  However, the name/value pair Mission_Name:"RST" is only prevalent in the first *n* objects.

For example, obj 43 contains:

```
43: Object
   ActFTEs: 0.00
   Actual: 10000
   Bud_Month: "FY Total"
   FY_CD: 2013
   Mission_Name: "VAO"
```

I have created the following function, but this still returns the full range of 143 values for the name/value pair related to "Bud_Month".

```
function get_dataArray() {
 var arr = [];
 var i= 0;
 for (i=0;i<jsonobj.row.length;i++) {   
    if (jsonobj.row[i][name]="RST") {
         arr[i] = jsonobj.row[i]["Bud_Month"];
    }    
 } 
 console.log(arr);
 return arr;
}
```

This returns:

```
["October", "FY Total", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "FY Total", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "November", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "FY Total", "October", "FY Total", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "FY Total", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "November", "October", "FY Total", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "FY Total", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "November", "October", "FY Total", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"…]
```

Does anyone have any advice for how to return the value for "Bud_Month" only in objects containing the name/value pair of Mission_Name:"RST" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (jsonobj.row[i][name]="HST") {
     arr[i] = jsonobj.row[i]["Bud_Month"];
}
```

Should probably be:

```
if (jsonobj.row[i][name]=="RST") {
     arr[i] = jsonobj.row[i]["Bud_Month"];
}
```

Comment: Good observation, but this was just a typo on my part (edited).  Still getting the full return of 143 values, however.  Thanks for catching this though. Don't mean to cause confusion.

Comment: Was the single-equals sign also a typo? Otherwise it would account for what you described.

Comment: Wow...thanks kufudo. I just showed off my novice skills.  Thanks for the insight. This worked.